# Check for empty string null?

Tags: java, string, guava, apache-commons

I have a json in which `userId` property is coming as string "null" -

```
"userId":"null"
```

I have a method which checks whether my string is null or not -

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String value) {
    return value == null || value.isEmpty();
}
```

But every time my above method returns back me as `false` for above `userId`? It should true since userId is null. Is there any other api in Guava or Apache Commons which can do this?

Comment: Have you also checked for the string equaling "null" eg value.equals("null")?

Comment: @copeg Instead of doing that way - Is there any other library which can do this for me?

Comment: @david There may be libraries that check for `null` and empty, but I don't think they check for the string "null".

Comment: Your method returns `false` because the string is not `null` or empty - it is `"null"` - in other words, a string consisting of 4 characters. Note that `"null"` is not the same as `null`. If you meant "no value", the JSON should have looked like this: `"userId":null` (note: no quotes around `null`).

Comment: You should try not to have a string with value "null" in your json in the first place...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `null` is not equal to the String `"null"`. `null` means that a given object has not been assigned a value, where the String `"null"` is a valid object. It contains the characters `n` `u` `l` `l`, which is a valid value for a String. You need to also check if the value is the literal string `"null"` in order to do what you want.

Correct Check

```
return value == null || value.isEmpty() || value.equals("null") ;
```

If you want to still maintain `"null"` as a valid username, then change whatever is sending the json to the following format, which should be interpreted as a literal `null` rather than a String with content `"null"`

```
"userId":null
```

Comment: what if someone wants the userId "null"?

Comment: @BarbiePylon If he has access to whatever produces the Json, the edit I added should work. If not, then he's out of luck, as there is the String `"null"` is used in place of literal `null` then there is no way to distinguish the two.

Comment: I agree with you this is something OP needs to make a decision about. I just thought I'd point it out!

Answer (score 4):

"null" is not the same as null.

"null" is a string 4 characters in length of the word "null".

null (no quotes) is just that--nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`{"userId":"null"}` equals `String userId = "null"` in java.

`{}` would equal `String userId = null` when unmarshalled.